# deploy website with production configuration automatically in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I have a question regarding Visual Studio 2010 publish feature which is used after you create a website (MVC framework) to push your dev changes to the live site.

I've never worked with MVC until a few weeks ago and 
I've noticed that before pushing the website code I have to change everywhere where I have localhost in the code and replace it with the domain name I'm pushing to. Then if I want to debug anything on my local machine I have to revert everything back to localhost from domain name.

**Q: Is there a way to not do this back and front url changing?**

Basically I think it boils down to needing a software package or sth that knows to deploy the website with production configuration.

Maybe have a local branch and a live branch? This involves merging files all the time.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it works with MVC, but one approach we use for web services development is to use the [web.config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx).

This means that the normal development stuff is in `Web.config` and we have separate configurations depending on the deployment environment `Web.staging.config` and `Web.production.config`.